# Access to UsbManagers setCurrentFunction() in Android?

Tags: java, android, usb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I can't seem to gain access to this function, it should allow me to set the usb mode on my device programatically (which is what I'm trying to do).

I can import the package where it is supposed to be, but it isn't available.

I know it exists as there are apps that use the function all over the place! its just my eclipse/ build environment can't find the damned thing.

Comment: It's a `public` method hidden from developers. Have a look at [this blog](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) about hidden methods and how to use them.